Why is nextjs re-rendering the whole page?
Im a newbie to nextjs. I want to create an app, where the layout(header/navbar) stays always fixed. Meaning, when the user clicks different links, only the main content should change, not the navbar. The page should not reload.
Below is my code so far:
// layout.tsx

import type { Metadata } from "next";
import Header from "../app/components/Header";
import Footer from "../app/components/Footer";

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "somestuff",
  description: "somestuff",
};

interface RootLayoutProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }: RootLayoutProps) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Header />
        <main>{children}</main>
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

// page.tsx
export default function HomePage() {
  return <div>HomePage</div>;
}

Header.tsx
import Link from "next/link";

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header>
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link href="/">Home</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/about">About</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link href="/contact">Contact</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
};

export default Header;


When i click the about or the other links, it directs me to the respectives pages, but with a full reload. I would like for the header to stay, and just the main content to change.
I tried wrapping the HomePage component with the Layout component, but didnt work.
Am I missing something here?

Try React.memo to prevent rerenders e.g.,
export default React.memo(Header, true); 

See also: React.memo
